# Dynamically change flags in 3ds Max with Maxscript

Tags: flags, maxscript

My main problem is that I don't know how to dynamically create a flag variable in 3ds Max with maxscript.  I would have hoped you could have just put a pound sign in front of a concatenated sting but that didn't work.

I'm writing a script that will dynamically create a flag for the material.  This works to change a materials' animation texture start time:
meditMaterials[21][#Maps][#Diffuse_Color__Bitmaptexture__011_0060_ifl].starttime = 101f

I want the material flag (#Diffuse_Color__Bitmaptexture__011_0060_ifl) to be dynamically created, based off user input to get input like:

#Diffuse_Color__Bitmaptexture__020_0040_ifl
 #Diffuse_Color__Bitmaptexture__046_0010_ifl
 #Diffuse_Color__Bitmaptexture__300_0020_ifl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create / get / set global variables using the globalVars structure:
http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_E7584E94_8696_421E_920C_2A83FCD9ABBF_htm

Does that point you in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think so, either that or I'm too much of a noob to know.
The problem is that I don't know how to combine stings or variables into a flag.  Is there a way to just declare something a flag?  It won't accept it as a string with a # at the beginning..

Comment: Nvm think I got it!!  Took away the pound sign and it works now

Comment: Sorry let me leave a better response.  
Problem: Needed to create a string that was dynamic to pass in as flag so it would set the image sequence on a material dynamically. 
Solution: Pass in the string you need without a pound sign at the beginning.  For some reason even though it has the # sign when you specify what your material image sequence is statically, you don't need it for passing in a string dynamically.